# Is there a way to force a Firebase Authentication ID Token to expire to see how my app would respond?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

After an hour of inactivity my app displays a blank screen, this is because (I think) the Firebase ID Token expires. Calls to our APIs do not work because they rely on a valid token, so refreshing the page makes everything work again.

I'd like to improve the user experience by either redirecting the user to another page or refreshing the page on their behalf (`window.location = 'https://example.com`), or something else..

I have listeners for both `onAuthStateChanged` and `onIdTokenChanged` and I think I need to *do something* when they detect the `auth/user-token-expired` error.

```
const unsubscribeOnAuthStateChanged = auth.onAuthStateChanged(
  (user) => {
    if (user) {
      // we're all good, continue
    } else {
      // log out the user
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(` ~ onAuthStateChanged ~ error`, error)
  },
)

const unsubscribeOnIdTokenChanged = auth.onIdTokenChanged(
  (user) => {
    console.log(` ~ getTokens ~ user`, user)
    if (user) {
      // we're all good, continue
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    // detect the error, if error.code === auth/user-token-expired, redirect the user
    console.log(` ~ onIdTokenChanged ~ error`, error)
  },
)
```

The trouble is that to test this I have to wait an hour or more each time, is there a way I can force a Firebase Authentication ID Token to expire to see how my app would respond?

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#setpersistence

Comment: Can anyone actually answer the question? I've tried ovewriting the stsToken in the indexDB storage but somehow the token still doesn't expire even after reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under what circumstances are you facing this issue? Firebase auto refreshes the token. You just need to ensure you always call getIdToken to retrieve the token.

For example, I have a custom fetch function which I use to call all my secure api, which will always attach the latest token.

```
export const apiFetch = async (url, options = {}, auth = true) => {
    if (!url) throw new Error('URL parameter is missing');
    
    const method = options.method || "GET";
    
    let authorization = {}
    if (auth) {
        const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
        authorization = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }

    url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + url;
    
    if (method.toUpperCase() !== "GET") {
        options = { ...options, headers: { ...options.headers, "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
    }
    
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        redirect: "follow",
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            ...authorization,
            ...options.headers,
        },
        body: options.body,
    }).then(handleErrors);
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think this is the correct answer. My fetch function uses the JWT for authorisation, but it does not try to get a new token if the old one has expired. I have made the change to it now, and will see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: If you use getIdToken() correctly, it will always auto check expire token and refreshes. You can go through the Firebase SDK JS GitHub page to see it using the isExpire function to check before returning the token

Answer (score 0):

As @Someone_Special said, Firebase will auto refresh the tokens for you. But just in case you want a new token irrespective of the current token is expired or not. You can pass true as a parameter in getIdToken() method this way:

```
 const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
```

This will force refresh the current token and invalidate it.

A snap from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using that already. I think @someone-special's answer is the correct one, so have implemented his suggestion.